# Does "my eyes get open" make any sense?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

> I want to sleep until my eyes open without this annoying alarm.

Is this sentence correct? If not, what should I write?

Comment: It's "grammatical", though I doubt any native speaker would say it. But unless you can explain why you think it might *not* be grammatical, this looks like proofreading to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it is. I think the OP knows it works without adding *get open* and he wanted to know if he could add it.

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers - it might be "grammatical" but it does not make very much sense and is not something a native speaker would say.

Comment: @Subjunctive: I wasn't even referring to the possibility of including *get* as per the title. So far as I'm concerned, the version in the question text is equally non-idiomatic. True, you can sometimes use *his eyes opened* with the exact meaning of *he awoke*, but that's only really because when you're talking about *someone else*, you've no easy way of knowing he's awake until he opens his eyes. But I don't think that equivalence works with a first person subject. The closest I would accept in this general context is *...until I **can** open my eyes...*

Comment: The question is grammatically correct.  I usually see people phrase things different, but the way you had it is fine.  Usually, "sleep until I wake up naturally".

Comment: Is this sentence correct: "1. People often say girls are selfish. Well, don't be the one."? I mean can I use "the one" instead of "Well, don't be the selfish girl"?